# Why i cant just connect directly to Firebase Realtime Database from my Arduino?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino

So today, i would like to ask help explaining how this code works and maybe a hint

The code below is not mine and i just got it from [here](https://github.com/robsonfagundes/arduino-gprs-sim-900-gps-neo-6m). The libraries are GSM-GPRS-GPS-Shield by Marco Martines and TinyGPSPlus that was also provided.

I can understand a bit in the code. And i just wanna know why i cant just connect directly to Firebase Realtime Database and what workarounds i can do?

Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <inetGSM.h>

InetGSM inet;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial serialGps(11, 10);

void setup() {
// Serial connection.
Serial.begin(19200);

Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
Serial.println(F("Starting App Arduino"));
Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));

// Start configuration of shield GPS NEO-6M with baudrate.
serialGps.begin(9600);

// Turn on GPRS
powerUpGprs();

// Start configuration of shield SIM900 with baudrate and  connect to internet.
if (gsm.begin(9600))
Serial.println(F("\nstatus=READY"));
else Serial.println(F("\nstatus=IDLE"));

// Mensure and show memory usage
Serial.println(F("\nMemory usage"));
Serial.print(freeRam());

void loop() {
serialGps.listen();
while (serialGps.available() > 0)  {
if (gps.encode(serialGps.read())) {
  // Get GPS position and send To API through inet.httpPOST()
  gsm.listen();
  // GPRS attach, put in order APN, username and password.
  if (inet.attachGPRS("internet", "", ""))
    Serial.println("status=ATTACHED");
  else Serial.println("status=ERROR");
  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CIFSR");

  Serial.print(F("\r\n\r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F(" GET GEOLOCATION & SEND TO API \r\n"));
  Serial.print(F("------------------------------------------------- \r\n"));
  // get geolocation
  String geo;
  geo.concat("lat=" + String(gps.location.lat(), 6));
  geo.concat("&lng=" + String(gps.location.lng(), 6));
  geo.concat("&spd=" + String(gps.speed.kmph()));
  geo.concat("&uid=gb1");
  // send2Api
  Serial.print(F("\nhttp://192.168.1.1/"));
  Serial.println(geo.c_str());
  Serial.print(F("\n"));
  gsm.SimpleWriteln("AT+CIFSR");
  inet.httpPOST("https://testdb-ec830-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/", 443, 
  "/geolocations", geo.c_str(), "", 100); // set url and port
      }
    }
  }

  int freeRam() {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval;
  int v;
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval);
  }

  void powerUpGprs() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  Serial.println(F("\nPower Up SIM900!"));
  }
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------- 
Starting App Arduino
------------------------------------------------- 

Power Up SIM900!
ATT: OK
RIC: AT

OK

DB:ELSE
ATT: OK
RIC: AT

OK

DB:ELSE
ATT: OK
RIC: AT

OK

DB:ELSE
ATT: OK
RIC: AT

OK

DB:CORRECT BR
ATT: OK
RIC: AT

OK

ATT: OK
RIC: AT&F

OK

ATT: OK
RIC: ATE0

OK

ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

ATT: +CPMS:
RIC: 
+CPMS: 0,35,0,35,0,35

OK

ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

ATT: SHUT OK
RIC: 
SHUT OK


status=READY

Memory usage
256ATT: ERROR
RIC: 
ERROR

DB:STARTING NEW CONNECTION
ATT: SHUT OK
RIC: 
SHUT OK

DB:SHUTTED OK
ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

DB:APN OK
ATT: OK
RIC: 
OK

DB:CONNECTION OK
ATT: ERROR
RIC: 
10.186.213.49

DB:ASSIGNED AN IP
status=ATTACHED


------------------------------------------------- 
 GET GEOLOCATION & SEND TO API 
------------------------------------------------- 

    http://10.190.86.139/geolocationslat=0.000000&lng=0.000000&uid=gb1

    ATT: OK
    RIC: 
    10.186.213.49

    DB:NOT CONN
    ATT: OK
    RIC: 
    ERROR

    DB:NOT CONN
    ATT: OK
    RIC: 
    ERROR

    DB:NOT CONN
    ATT: ERROR
    RIC: 
    10.186.213.49

    DB:ALREADY HAVE AN IP
    ATT: ERROR
    RIC: 
    ERROR

    ATT: ERROR
    RIC: 
    ERROR

    status=ATTACHED
```

Thank you so much to everyone who would help me!

Comment: The question isn't very clear. The code you obtained is for using SIM900 and NEO-6M. Are you saying you aren't actually using these devices? What do you mean by "direct" to Firebase? You need a network connection.

Comment: im sorry for not being clear in my question. im not an native english speaker.

i actually had the modules(arduino uno, sim900 and ne06m gps module.) on hand.

i just wanna know why it wont connect to firebase -realtime database and is their any workarounds for it to send the location data to firebase?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why it's not working. The code you show is using the GSM module for network setup. Perhaps yours is nit connected properly. Can you test that first? Perhaps they connecting to a known server. The for firebase I recommend checking a firebase tutorial to set it up for your own needs. If you copied this code, it will be tailored for someone else's setup.

Comment: The way i understand the code is that, i only needed to change the APN, URL and PORT. I read something that, the Firebase only accepts POST in HTTPS only. And i think the library or the GSM module itself only supports HTTP. Is it possible to have the module send the data through Firebase Cloud Functions and have some sort of converting HTTP to HTTPS before going to Realtime Database? I`m sorry if you get confused again im not that used to use the right terminologies in terms of programming.